# Interpreting debugger output for my bug using Qt and QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I have a bug in my program that makes it crash. I cannot find it no matter how much I search. It is incredibly random as it jumps sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. I've manged to reproduce it quite consistently using a debug version of my program and the QtCreator in debug mode. However, when the bug occurs I get this trace in the debugger output and a line in dissasembler which means nothing to me:

[image]

Can anyone help me interpret what this error means?

Comment: That's a weird stack trace. Can you show the line numbers or do they not exist? I would suggest that you build a debug build of Qt yourself if that's the case. Then we can at least see which lines are being executed.

Comment: Problem is my time is short I don't have the time to build Qt. And right friking now, I can't make the error happened again. I have some valgrind output. But I opened up another question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696364/detecting-memory-corruption-that-occurss-by-writing-free-memory)